# Get the controls contained in an ItemsControl in code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, itemscontrol

When I get the `ItemsSource` of my `ItemsControl`, it's return me an `ObservableCollection` of the view model bounds to my user controls but I want to get an `ObservableCollection` of my user controls.
How can I get the user controls contained in my `ItemsControl` ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to call ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement to get the "root-control" for each data item displayed. And the you can use the VisualTreeHelper to iterate over the controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx). You can probably use [ContainerFromIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromindex.aspx) or [ContainerFromItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem.aspx) methods to get the container of each element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FindByName of the root control, or go through the visual tree with this function

```
public static FrameworkElement FindByName(string name, FrameworkElement root)
{
    Stack<FrameworkElement> tree = new Stack<FrameworkElement>();
    tree.Push(root);

    while (tree.Count > 0)
    {
        FrameworkElement current = tree.Pop();
        if (current.Name == name)
            return current;

        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            if (child is FrameworkElement)
                tree.Push((FrameworkElement)child);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```